# React Native: onChangeText is not updating hook state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

So I'm trying to do something very simple in my react native application, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.  I have a component in my native application that allows the user to create a post.  The user can simply input the text that they would like as the body of their post.  Of course I have decided to use the `TextInput` component for this and I am setting my body state by using `onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}`.  When I click the `create_post` button in the upper right of the header I get "" as a value for the body.

I have other text input components throughout my application that work just as intended but for some reason this one is not.  I have looked all over online and no one seems to have this issue.  They only have an issue with it in a class component and not a functional component like the one I have here:

```
import React,{useLayoutEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { TextInput,ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Button } from './../components/Button';

const CreatePost = ({navigation,route}) => {
    const [body,onChangeText] = useState('');
    const [media,setMedia] = useState('');

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title: 'New Post',
            headerRight: () => (
                <Button style={{marginRight:40,fontSize:20}} title="Post" textColor="#0d00ff" onPress={create_post} />
            )
        })
    },[])

    const create_post = () => {
        const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0];

        console.log({body});  // expected: 'some text', result:""
        const post = {
            pid: 0,
            username: 'head_honcho',
            body: body
        }
        
        // makes call to database
        navigation.navigate('HomeTab',{screen: 'Home',params:{post:post}});

    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{padding:16}}>
            <TextInput placeholder="What's happening?" keyboardType="default" value={body} style={{fontSize:20}} onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}/>
            {/* <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', position:'absolute',bottom:0,left:0,right: 0}}>
                <FontAwesome5 name="photo-video" size={20} />
                <Text>Add Media</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> */}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default CreatePost
```

I think this seems pretty straight forward and I feel silly having to ask a question so basic.  My only other thought is that it has something to do with `useLayoutEffect` and that when create_post is called that it only has access to the initial state and not the updated one.  If anyone has any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong that would be great. TIA!

**EDIT**

Just shortly after posting this I decided to see what would happen if I let useLayoutEffect check for updates in my body variable.  Sure enough the body of the post actually came through as it should have.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title: 'New Post',
            headerRight: () => (
                <Button style={{marginRight:40,fontSize:20}} title="Post" textColor="#0d00ff" onPress={create_post} />
            )
        })
    },[body])
```

But I would still like to know why this is?  Why doesn't onChangeText set my body variable as mentioned in the react documentation?

Comment: because the create_post function only gets the initial state variables when you declare it in useLayoutEffect without dependency. so in order for create_post function to get the state you need you have to re render it via useEffect(() => { ..etc },[body])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can do it like this.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        title: 'New Post',
    })
 },[])

useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
            <Button style={{marginRight:40,fontSize:20}} title="Post" textColor="#0d00ff" onPress={create_post} />
        )
 },[body])
```

This way only the button is re rendered

Comment: Feels redundant to be using useLayoutEffect and useEffect in that case.  Why not just put everything in useEffect then?  Plus wouldn't putting the body in useEffect re render the component anyway?

Comment: redundant? no. this ways tells us that the header right is dependent on variable changes. not the whole navigation options. but its your choice.

Comment: Ok that makes a little more sense.  Sorry, just seemed a little overkill to be using both methods instead of one or the other.